# How to make one line chart with 3 tables in power bi

Tags: powerbi, relational-database, linechart

I have two tables that aren't unique in the same columns.
I want to draw a line chart with value and axis from table 1 (ritemvalue, and year) and legend from table 2 (ritemsimilartitle).
I created a third table that is Included unique "ritemTitle" column.
I created a slicer with third table that select "ritemtitle".
It is possible each "ritemtitle" has more than 1 "ritemsimilartitle " .
Please let me know if you have solution for this.

[image: Sample Table Screenshot]

Comment: This should be achievable easily. You need to create a one to many relationship between table 3 - Table1 and table3 - table 2. Please add what have you tried?

Comment: The 3rd table you do not need, drag the first column of the first table in the slicer and you are good.

Comment: @Aldert thanks for answering. i should do this, because of the columns are not unique and i can't make any relation between them.

Comment: @Gangula thanks for answering . i did it but it didn't work. note, i want to choose legend(ritemsimilartitle) from table 2 and value and axis(Year) from table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a one to many relationship between table3 -> table 1 and table 3 <-> table 2. Then you should be able to do it.

Edit : Change the relationship between table 2 and table 3 as both side relationship.
[image]

Comment: thanks for answering . i did it but it didn't work.
note, i want to choose legend(ritemsimilartitle) from table 2 and value and axis(Year) from table 1.

Comment: Did you create the relation?

Comment: @Ali, what do you mean by it didn't work? Please add a screenshot in your question of how the visuals turned after trying this?

Comment: @Gangula , sure , i want something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBKAJ.png

Comment: and whats happening when you try to create this with the method that is suggested in the answer?

Comment: @Gangula chart needs to fix..it said: there is a missing relationship between this fields

Comment: thank you very much. it worked..but value are mistake, do you know why?